# Why does nature have higher atomic nuclei if Iron(Fe) has higher binding energy per nucleon?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, binding-energy, elements, stellar-evolution

From the binding energy per nucleon (B.E./A) vs atomic number (Z) we know that Iron (Fe) is most stable nuclei in the nature. Here comes the question that if nature has found the stable nuclei then why does it has nuclei in higher mass region?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do elements on the Binding Energy per Nuclear Molecule after Iron (most stable) even form?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191195/)

Comment: Actually, depending on how you calculate it, nickel-62 beats iron-56; see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/15951/123208 for details.

Comment: Please let us know if the answer linked by Thorondor is sufficient, or if you need a more in-depth answer.